# alter url with jQuery when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to alter a portion of the url when a link is clicked.

```
$('.slavearticle a.headlinelink').click(function () {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    url = url.replace('/something.example.com', 'betterexample.no');
    console.log(url);
    return false;
});
```

The desired out come here would be that if the url were something.example.com/index.html it would be changed to betterexample.no/index.html everything after the / would never change

This seems to work but I have an issue. "something.example.com" needs to be more dynamic

> $('.slavearticle a.headlinelink').click(function(){
>
> > var url = $(this).attr('href');
> >
> > url = url.replace(something.example.com, 'betterexample.no');
> >
> > window.location.href = url;
> >     });

The downside is that I have 50 different sites that need this feature. Is there a way to just get everything after the / so that this will work for any site?

Comment: Check out pushstate https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: You never set the href with the new value! And you seem to have an extra / in the first part.

Comment: and you want the link to be followed on that click? if that's the case why not just redirecting there without replacing the link?

Comment: Anyway you want to redirect the link , then why not place the initial href as the url you want to chnage

Answer (score 0):

Add one extra line:
$(this).attr('href',url);

```
 $('.slavearticle a.headlinelink').click(function(){

        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        url = url.replace('/something.example.com','betterexample.no');
        $(this).attr('href',url);
        console.log(url);
        return false;

        });
```

Comment: and lose the leading / and return true if you want the link to be followed

Comment: I get "index.html" in my console but I need it to be altered to output "betterexample.no/index.html"

Comment: Can you post original url of the link you are clicking on. href value i mean.

Answer (score 0):

When you get an attr with jQuery, you just have the string, not the reference of where it was taken from, so when you replace it, you are just replacing the string not the actual href of the link. With this you are replacing the href in the link:

```
$('.slavearticle a.headlinelink').click(function () {
    var url = $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href').replace('something.example.com', 'betterexample.no'));
    console.log(url);
    return false;
});
```

You are better off doing it with plain JavaScript I think:

```
$('.slavearticle a.headlinelink').click(function () {
    this.href = this.href.replace('/something.example.com', 'betterexample.no');
    console.log(this.href);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: return false will cancel the link!

Comment: The first example does nothing except write to the console

Comment: Well that's what he was doing, we don't know if he needs it that way somehow. I just edited his code to replace the href as he asked.

Comment: His code already did that. No improvement. Second example already posted by others.

Answer (score 0):

Here I just change all links that contain "something.example.com"

```
$('.slavearticle a.headlinelink[href*="something.example.com"]').click(function () {
    var newUrl = $(this).attr("href").replace("something.example.com","betterexample.no");
    $(this).attr('href',newUrl);
    // do NOT return false if you want the link to work
});
```

Earlier suggestion:

```
$('.slavearticle a.headlinelink').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the link since we navigate
    var newUrl = $(this).attr("href").replace("something.example.com","betterexample.no");
    location = newUrl;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand all the requirements, but is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/cg7m3/

I basically just added `window.location.href = url;`, and got rid of the starting forward slash in your replace string.

```
$('.slavearticle a.headlinelink').click(function () {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    url = url.replace('something.example.com', 'google.com');
    console.log(url);
    window.location.href = url;
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @mplungjan My fault, added.

Comment: Funny - identical to my first suggestion I made :)

Comment: this worked for me but now I need something.example.com to be replaceable with any url

Comment: @user2882684 Then replace it with a different string? Is there an example you have in mind that doesn't work?

Comment: the downside is that I have 50 different sites that need this feature. is there a way to just get everything after the / so that this will work for any site?

Comment: @user2882684 Use the .match() function to write/google for a regular expression that matches the path of the url and appends it to whatever subdomain you need it to

Answer (score -2):

Try this one, This is work for me

```
$('.slavearticle a.headlinelink').click(function () {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    url = url.replace('something.example.com', 'betterexample.no');
    console.log(url);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: What did you do if anything apart from removing the /

Comment: This worked out for me and I have tested it. Please try the above example what i am given and let me know

Comment: 1) it does not change anything 2) it goes nowhere. All it does is write the changed url to the console

Comment: This will do nothing other than show a modified string value in the console and stop the link working.

Comment: here we are change the url and for links to be work we have to be write  the following code after the console.log "window.location.href = url;"